# How to improve model latency for deployment

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torch, torchscript

**Question:**
How to improve model latency for web deployment without retraining the models? What is the checklist that I should mark to improve the model speed?

**Context:**
I have multiple models that process a video sequentially on one machine with one K80 GPU; each model takes around 5 mins to process a video that is 1 min long. What ideas and suggestions should I try to improve each model latency without changing the model architecture? How should I structure my thinking about this problem?

Comment: Which framework do you use? Pytorch? Tensorflow? Usually to be scallable and have good performance you can use inference server like Nvidia triton

Answer (score 0):

1. Sampling frames is the easiest technique if it fits your usecase. Picking every 5th frame for inference will cut your inference time by ~5x(theoretically). Caveat is if you are working on tasks like object tracking you will have reduced accuracy.
2. fp32 to fp16 might increase your inference speed.
3. Batch Inference always lowers inference time by a decent bit. Ref: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/1806#issuecomment-752834571
4. Multiprocess Concurrent Inference is basically spinning up more than 1 instances of the same model on seperate processes and infer parallely. `torch` has a multiprocessing module [`torch.multiprocessing`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/multiprocessing.html). I havent ever used this but i assume the setup would be somewhat significant and complex.

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia Tesla K80 is quite an old GPU (2014), so that's probably the reason why the processing time is so long. If your machine has a modern Intel CPU and/or iGPU you could try [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html). It's a heavily optimized toolkit for inference. [Here](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_performance_benchmarks_openvino.html) are some performance benchmarks.

You can find a full tutorial on how to convert the PyTorch model [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/102-pytorch-onnx-to-openvino).
Some snippets below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[pytorch,onnx]
```

**Save your model to ONNX**

OpenVINO cannot convert PyTorch model directly for now but it can do it with ONNX model. This sample code assumes the model is for computer vision.

```
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH)
torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "model.onnx", opset_version=11)
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert ONNX model**

The Model Optimizer is a command line tool which comes from OpenVINO Development Package so be sure you have installed it. It converts the ONNX model to IR, which is a default format for OpenVINO. It also changes the precision to FP16 for even better performance (there shouldn't be much accuracy drop). Run in command line:

```
mo --input_model "model.onnx" --input_shape "[1,3, 224, 224]" --mean_values="[123.675, 116.28 , 103.53]" --scale_values="[58.395, 57.12 , 57.375]" --data_type FP16 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference on the CPU**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device e.g. CPU. Use AUTO if you want to deploy on the best device you have.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="AUTO")

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.